# Cannot access elements with a specific attribute from my dao (Android Room)

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, dao, entities

I am making a toDoList app with multiple users. I have two entities. One is User and the other one is Task

```
@Entity(tableName = "tasks")
data class Task(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id : Int,
val taskUserId : Int,
val taskName : String,
val taskDescription : String,
var taskPriority : Int)


@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
@PrimaryKey
val userId : Int,
val userName : String,
val password : String)
```

As you can see the two entities need to have one thing in common and that would be the users id so I could query for tasks based on the users id. This is what my dao looks like:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM users")
fun getAllUsers() : LiveData<List<User>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskUserId LIKE :userId ORDER BY taskPriority DESC")
fun getAllUsersTasks(userId : Int) : LiveData<List<Task>>

@Insert
suspend fun saveUser(user : User)

@Insert
suspend fun saveTask(task : Task)
}
```

And here are the other model elements:

```
class TaskRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {

var userId : Int = 0
val allTasks = userDao.getAllUsersTasks(userId)
val allUsers : LiveData<List<User>> = userDao.getAllUsers()

suspend fun saveUser(user : User){
    userDao.saveUser(user)
}

suspend fun saveTask(task : Task){
    userDao.saveTask(task)
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private val taskRepository : TaskRepository

val allTasks : LiveData<List<Task>>
val allUsers : LiveData<List<User>>
private var userId  : Int = 0


init {
    val taskDao = UserTasksDatabase.getDatabase(application)!!.userDao()
    taskRepository = TaskRepository(taskDao)
    allTasks = taskRepository.allTasks
    allUsers = taskRepository.allUsers
    taskRepository.userId = this.userId
}


fun saveUser(user: User) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    taskRepository.saveUser(user)
}

fun saveTask(task: Task) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    taskRepository.saveTask(task)
}

fun setUserId(id : Int){
    this.userId = id
}

fun getUserId() : Int{
    return this.userId
    }

}
```

When the user pushes the login or the sign up button I set the user's id in the viewModel

```
 logInButton.setOnClickListener {
        val userName: String = userNameEditText.text.toString()
        val password: String = passwordEditText.text.toString()
        val id: Int = IdMaker.generateId(userName)
        val user = User(id, userName, password)

        if(listOfAllUsers.contains(user)){
            sharedViewModel.setUserId(id)
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Welcome $userName", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.fl_activity_main, MainFragment())
                commit()
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "The user already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

But when i try to access the users in the main fragment and set them on my recyclerview I get nothing. And I can't really see what am I missing.

```
sharedViewModel.allTasks.observe(this, Observer {tasks ->
        tasks.let { adapter.setTasks(it) }
    })
```

I'm sorry if a question is a bit simple but I hope I will gain some insight in what am I missing.

Side note: The recyclerview is set up properly and tested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting the `TaskRepository.userId` correctly.

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val taskRepository : TaskRepository
    private var userId  : Int = 0

    init {
        ...
        // init is called only once at the start of this viewModel's instance creation
        // Here, you set your repository's userId to 0
        taskRepository.userId = this.userId
    }
}
```

At the instance creation of your `MainViewModel`, you set the `userId` of its `TaskRepository` instance to 0, which in your following codes is not changed anymore. Upon your login button click, you do call:

```
sharedViewModel.setUserId(id)
```

but the function alters only the viewModel's `userId` property, not the `userId` property of your `TaskRepository` instance. So try:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private lateinit var taskRepository : TaskRepository
    val allTasks = taskRepository.allTasks
    val allUsers = taskRepository.allUsers


    // remove init {}
    
    fun setUserId(id : Int){
        // set up the repository only after userId is known
        val taskDao = UserTasksDatabase.getDatabase(application)!!.userDao()
        taskRepository = TaskRepository(taskDao, id)
    }
}
```

And alter your `TaskRepository` class:

```
class TaskRepository(private val userDao: UserDao, private val userId: Int) {
    val allTasks: LiveData<List<Task>> 
        get() = userDao.getAllUsersTasks(userId)
    val allUsers: LiveData<List<User>>
        get() = userDao.getAllUsers()

    ...
}
```